# условие if в jquery

Tags: jquery, if

как присвоить стиль конкретному тегу? У меня выводятся карточки с наименованием товаров и нужно сделать, чтобы при выводе товаров, если длина имени товара превышает 24 символа, то присвоить тегу с классом .name и атрибутом data-id=id стиль margin:-40px auto 0px.

```
if($('.name').text().length>24) {
    var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    $('.name [data-id="id"]').attr("style","margin:-40px auto 0px");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Тут нужен не if, а each.

```js
$('.name').each(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    var length = $this.text().length;
    
    if (length < 24) {
        $this.addClass('red');
    }
});
```

```css
.red {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='name'>fdsafsdafadsfasdfasdfasdfasdfsdafsadfasdfadsf</div>
<div class='name'>dsfaadsfasdfasdf</div>
<div class='name'>dsafdasfasdfafadfasdfasdfasdf</div>
<div class='name'>fadsfasdfasdfasdfasdf</div>
<div class='name'>fadsfasdfasdfadsfafdasfadsfdsafasdfdasfasdfa</div>
<div class='name'>fdasfafdsfasdfafdasfdas</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Что-то мне кажется (по наличию `this`) что у вас уже есть какой-то перебор элементов. Тогда ничего с `data-id` делать не нужно.

```
if ($(this).text().length > 24) {
    $(this).css({ margin: "-40px auto 0px" });
}
```